# Using Solr to search multiple database tables

Tags: solr

I have about 40 tables in database and we are planning to use Solr to search. So, when users enter a search they can choose some or all tables to search for data. These 40 tables are not related to each other. I tried search on single table and it worked great but I am not clear on how to approach the above scenario in Solr. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the table name to the solr schema.

For example add a field table:

```
<field name="table" type="string" indexed="true" stored="stored" multiValued="false"/>
```

Now you can choose to facet on tables:

```
&fq=table:(users OR log)
```

You need to make the value stored, to know from which table something comes and decide your process strategy for the results.

I think this is a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Are you saying I should put all data from different tables into one document, with extra column to identify the table? But the columns are different across the tables, and also primary keys on some tables are GUIDs and some are integers. How does it work?

Comment: Solr has only one schema (at least when you work with one core), so the suggestion from the developers of solr is to flatten your data into a single index: [flatten data](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes). 

But to do this, you must initially designed it this way. So if you have primary keys which are sometimes guids and sometimes integers, it will not work very well. What you can try is to add a dynamic field for those. [dynamic_fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Dynamic+Fields)

Comment: I work at a rather big project, which tries to make all their magazines searchable, we import all the data from various databases into one mongo database, so we have control over how the data is organized. That helps somewhat. But I think in your case this is not an option.

Comment: I meant store it the primary keys as String not as dynamic field, which is something entirely different. This is not great for performance, but works for different typed fields.

Comment: Thank you for the response! If I store the primary keys as string, should I save them in the same field in the document? Also, shouldn't the schema needs a unique key? If I save them in the same field, there might be more than one record with the same primary key. How does that work? Also, how does the full import query and delta query looks like? Do I need to use union SQL statements? Sorry, too many questions, but I am at loss here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solr is very unlike a database, so a concept of primary key doesn't exist. The fields you send together to solr to store will be retrieved together. E.g. our id looks like: `<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />`. And for your case you want a key: `<field name="table" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />`.

It doesn't matter that the id key is duplicated, as long as the key is not duplicated in one table. So table and id should be unique together. I don't know about the import queries, I use an abstraction layer.

Comment: But what we did, was overloading the save method in our ORM. If we save something, we fetch all the keys and send it to SOLR. We also have batch scripts which does a lot of records at once. The setup is somewhat complicated, because we don't send it directly to SOLR, but first to celery so it is asynchronous sent to SOLR. 

But solr is not a database, so you don't need a primary key. It will couple all fields together. E.g. we have a field classification, if I ask for some classification, like `fq=classification:test`, I get all the associated fields I asked for.

Comment: In our setup content-type and id is unique. An image and an article could have the same id, but because we store the content-type and id we can differentiate  in the results and know how to get the data from the database.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have few more questions. In a single data-config.xml file, can I have multiple documents i.e. multiple document tags? If so, when to have multiple documents in data-config.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to explain how to store the table name into the created "table"-field.

This is, what I was looking for:

***TemplateTransformer***: Can be used to overwrite or modify any existing Solr field ... The value assigned to the field is based on a static template string ...
[Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#TemplateTransformer)

**data-config.xml**:

```xml
<entity name="Books" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
  <!-- other fields -->
  <field column="Table" template="Books"/>
</entity>

<entity name="Movies" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
  <!-- other fields -->
  <field column="Table" template="Movies"/>
</entity>
```

**schema.xml**:

```xml
<field name="Table" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```